# What's the proper syntax for a shorthand file_exists if/else?

Tags: php

I currently have this:

```
    $imgpath = $domainurl.'images/games/'.$name.'_icon.jpg';
    $img = (file_exists($imgpath) ? '<img src="1">' : '<img src="2">');
```

I want to show img 1 (original) if the file exists, and show img 2 (default) if the file does not exist.

Right now, the code will only show the 2nd image, even if the 1st one does exist.

You can see this at: http://crystalarcade.com/arcade/category/all

Comment: Show your full code, unless you're really echoing 1 and 2 as your image url's.

Comment: I did this for clutters sake, there is a lot of code (which is mostly just HTML code being output). These are 2 actual image urls: http://crystalarcade.com/images/games/symbiosis_icon.jpg (1). http://crystalarcade.com/images/games/default.jpg (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks for a file named, literally, `$imgpath`. Remove the single quotes. Furthermore, `$domainurl` sounds like it's a URL. `file_exists` may work on URLs depending on your PHP settings, but if possible, you should give it a path on the local filesystem.

Comment: you can even remove the parentheses (before file_exists and the;)

Comment: Look at http://http://crystalarcade.com/arcade/category/all.

It's making ALL of my icons the default one.

Comment: @AJGreene: You'll want to pass `file_exists` a filesystem path rather than a URL. In this case, you'll probably want to concatenate the document root with `'images/games/'.$name.'_icon.jpg'`.

Comment: @icktoofay make this an answer so I can accept it. EDIT: WOW I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the qoutes `''` from around `$imgpath`, and the `()` are not necessary-

```
$img = file_exists($imgpath) ? '<img src="1">' : '<img src="2">';
```

Comment: I had it like this before I added the quotes around it. It still doesn't work.

Comment: what does not work? Is it not setting `$img`, or are you only getting `<img src="2">`?

Comment: I'm only getting the 2nd image. I should have specified that.

Comment: @AJGreene If your posted code already has issues, add that to the question.

Comment: What do you get when you echo `$imgpath`? Is `$domainurl` & `$name` set, giving a correct file name?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of PHP shorthand is discouraged and should be avoided.

Please use proper IF statements.

See PSR 0 to PSR 2 php development standards

Side note:
at first you might think the shorthand writing is more compact and logic, but unlike with  a full IF statement most people can't figure out which case will happen.